# Can you initialize variables in the var declation section using a function in Delphi?

Tags: delphi-10.4-sydney

I'm kind of rusty on Delphi. Used in the early nineties but am C# programmer now. I'm current working on a Delphi project.

I have to transform a lot of .pas file for localization of strings. I've written a C# program to do the transformation. The idea is to parse all .pas files an everywhere there a Dutch text string replace it with call to our language routines. I now find the problem that there a lot of constants in many of the units that have to transform to variables. The current implementation does it like this but this doesn't compile:

before:
unit _TypesConstantsCommon;

```
interface

uses System.SysUtils;

const
  

    cDEELPRJN_OMSCHRIJVING_OPSTELLEN_OFFERTE = 'Opstellen offerte';
```

after:

```
unit _TypesConstantsCommon;

interface

uses System.SysUtils;

var

      cDEELPRJN_OMSCHRIJVING_OPSTELLEN_OFFERTE:string = TLanguagesManager.GetSingleton.GetText(c_TypesConstantsCommon1);
```

Is this at all possible? If not what should I generate to get this done?

Comment: Can't you test this yourself by trying to compile the code? The typical way to do what you're asking is to declare the variable at the top of the unit and initialize it to a value in an `initialization` section at the bottom of the unit.

Comment: You should use a proper Delphi parser

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks Ken that was the kind of pointer I was looking for. Ok make the transform a bit more complex but very doable.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I'm using DGrok from GitHub. It doesn't support the latest language changes unfortunately but the Lexer does the job pretty good.